# Why is SSLCertificateKeyFile needed for Apache?

Tags: security, apache, pki

What's the technical reason that SSLCertificateKeyFile is needed (the private key)? Where is that used and for what?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The SSL certificate file contains the X.509 certificate (which, in turn, contains a public key used for encryption).  The SSL Certificate *Key* File contains the private key corresponding to the public key in the certificate.  In order for the webserver to encrypt *and* decrypt traffic, it must have both the public key (certificate) and corresponding private key.  Apache, unlike a lot of other server products, stores the key and certificate in separate files.  Java-based products, for example, typically use Java KeyStore files, which are an encrypted database containing both the certificate and private key.

Answer (score 23):

Usually there are three directives included:

```
SSLCertificateFile /opt/csw/apache2/certs/icompany/publicCert.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /opt/csw/apache2/certs/icompany/chain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/csw/apache2/certs/icompany/PrivateKeyCert.pem
```

`SSLCertificateFile` should contain only the public portion of your certificate, which you want to deliver from the website to the client.

If `SSLCertificateChainFile` is specified, the webserver will attach the associated certificates (to build up a whole chain to a Root CA) to the webserver certificate.
You could also put the private portion of your certificate into the file as specified in `SSLCertificateFile` but this is **NOT** recommended for security reasons (for example the webserver has a bug, buffer oferflow occurs and prints out the private key to the attacker).

Instead put only the private key in a separate file and declare it in `SSLCertificateKeyFile`

Answer (score 0):

For an overview of public key cryptography, including the use of private keys:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography#How_it_works

And a detailed breakdown of all the steps used in TLS, the protocol your server uses for https traffic, which shows exactly where the private key gets used:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: How about a brief summary like: “In the public-key cryptography, the private key is used to …”?

Comment: He only has to read 3 sentences into the first link to get that summary. If you can answer your question with a quick read of a wiki article, it's a really poor question to ask other human beings here.

Comment: He maybe asks for the technical (and maybe not conceptual) reason, which is specific to apache. I tried to answer this the apache way.