# OpenSSL RSA extract public key with .cer format

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, rsa, cer, public-key-exchange

I'm using `openSSL` to create `RSA` `public and private key`. I create success, and output is 2 keys with format `private_key.pem` and `public_key.pem`.

So, the requirement is public key need to be in `.cer` `extension`, `Base 64 format` and start with header: `-----BEGIN`

I do some researches but can't find to to convert `pem` to `cer`

Any ideas?
Thanks.

P/S: Here is script that I used to generate key:

```
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out public_key.pem
```

**Update**

Finally, I found solution for this, just for those who need it.

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\share\openssl.cnf
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048 -sha256 -passout pass:abc123
openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -key private_key.pem -out public_key.cer -days 3650
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert .pem into .key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979171/how-to-convert-pem-into-key)

Comment: I think this question is "how do I make a certificate from a key?".  There's mild ambiguity (per an answer) about CER as CERtificate and as Canonical Encoding Rules for ASN.1 data.  But I think there're enough clues in the question that they mean certificate.

Answer (score 0):

For your public key to start with header: -----BEGIN, directly generate a base64 certificate with the private key.

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key key.pem -out ca.crt
```

This will generate a self-signed certificate embedded with the relative public key which is valid for 5 years. Or use,

```
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out cert.csr
```

to generate a certificate signing request and get it signed by a Root.

Answer (score -1):

**PEM** is a normative encoding format (see [RFC-7468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#appendix-B)), specifically designed to be included in mails, so it is only using a basic character set. **DER** is another normative encoding format, using a binary encoding scheme.

**CER** **is not** normative, it is a file extension often used to convey certificates (or, less often, keys).

Since CER is sometimes used as an extension for files containing **DER** encoded cryptographic material, people misuse the **CER** acronym and talk about CER encoding. But this has no sense. Finally, some other people talk about **CER** files for **PEM** encoded material.

> I do some researches but can't find to to convert pem to cer

You will not, this has no sense: the way you have created your keys made them already PEM encoded.

So, the only thing you may need to do is converting your key files encoded in **PEM** to **DER** format, whatever the filename extension is.

To do that, use openssl:

```
openssl rsa -inform PEM -in private_key.pem -outform DER -out private_key.der
openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -in public_key.pem -outform DER -out public_key.der
```